# How to put UIView inside of UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview

I want to put my UIView inside of UICollectionView(on top) that on scroll it scrolls with UICollectionView content. It's possible to put it on header part in UITableView, I did it, but in UICollectionView I cannot achieve the same effect. How can I do it?

I have created [GitHub repo with sample](https://github.com/orkhanalizade/UICollectionViewTest). If anyone could help me with it.

In UITableView I add UIView inside of UITableView and it stays there, but in UICollectionView it stays behind of UICollectionView. I want that it(UICollectionView sections) will stay under the UIView and on scroll all(UIView & UICollectionView sections) will scroll together.

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: @Abhi yes. You can look at GitHub

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as collection view footer or header, because the layout can be very different depending on your needs, but, you have a couple of function that can help you for example:
[registerClass(_:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/registerClass:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:)

or

[registerNib(_:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/registerNib:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:)

depending if you are using a nib file or not.

I'm not sure but you will also need to provide the height of the view in the layout delegate
[UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by dragging your `UIView` on to your cellidentifier of `UICOllectionView`
Like i did see in snapshot:
[image]

here View is my `UIView` which i added to `UICollectionView` and it scroll with the `CollectionView`